# How should I integrate Storybooks with React, Webpack, Docker, lighttpd?

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, lighttpd, storybook

I'm working on a Dockerized react app. It is built with Webpack 4. As part of the CI process on this project, the app is deployed to both staging and production environments, where it's served with `lighttpd`. What I would like to do is have a Storybooks page that is accessible on the staging site, but not on prod.

There are a few issues here that are making it hard for me to figure out the best approach.

- As part of the CI process the app is built and automatically deployed to the staging environment when a commits are pushed to any git branch with a name of the form `staging/...`
- The switches that configure the app for staging vs. prod are primarily in the project's webpack config.
- That build process is managed by a dockerfile which I can edit. I can run `yarn` commands (to build a static storybooks bundle, e.g.) in that dockerfile. But the same dockerfile is used for both staging and prod and I'd prefer not to have to create a separate one.
- I would prefer not to have to change the `react-router` routes at all, because the routes file should (ideally) be the same for staging and prod.
- I'm generally a little fuzzy on how/whether a user could enter a URL on the staging environment that bypasses `react-router` somehow and shows the static storybooks page. The networking aspects of web dev are not my strong suit. I'm usually just building and styling components.

My approach thus far has been to simply build a static storybooks bundle by adding a `RUN yarn storybooks` line to the dockerfile, but this fails in a couple of ways. 1) It runs for both staging and prod.
2) It seems to build the static storybooks bundle (i.e. the dockerfile output shows the storybooks building via it's own, internal webpack process successfully), but I'm not sure how to actually view it in the browser.

I hope that all makes some sense. What I'm looking for is general "best practices"-style guidance. Please let me know if I can provide any additional info and thanks for the time.

Comment: With what soultion did you came up with in the end?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to `RUN yarn storybooks` as a separate process using `concurrently` in package.json script named `prod` and run the right command by using a `--build-arg` in dockerfile

*in your Dockerfile*

```
#EXEMPLE docker build --build-arg running_env=preprod
ARG buildenv
RUN yarn run $buildenv
```

Do not forget to expose the right ports ... my script in `package.json` looks like this :
`"storybook": "start-storybook -c storybook/ --ci -p 3007"`

and as for the routing you could add a link and redirect to the storybooks page. I am currently figuring this out too.